# EnableCors without creation of Controller Instance

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I have next controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*",
     SupportsCredentials = true)]
public class ResourceController {
    public ResourceController (ResourceRepository repository) {
    }
}
```

Where ResourceRepository is defined as

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true)]
public class ResourceRepository {

}
```

But when the browser issues OPTIONS request it turned out that .AttributeBasedPolicyProviderFactory tries to create an instance of ResourceController just to look for its attributes. As a result instanciation is failed with SecurityException "Request for principal permission failed."

Is it possible configure CORS for ASP.NET API so that it will not instanciate the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can host your Web API with OWIN and enable CORS for OWIN pipeline (see `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` NuGet package). You should register CORS middleware before Web API middleware. So as your CORS middleware goes first it will be executed before request even reaches Web API infrastructure.